# Can anyone tell me what carry the torch means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

It is from the website of Me Too movement.

> We're honoring the women who paved the way for us.
> The women who inspire us to *carry the torch* and continue the work.

Does it mean to be a dedicated leader in this sentence?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Did you have a look in a dictionary before you asked the question here? [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/carry-the-torch), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/carry-the-torch), [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/carry+the+torch)... If so can you see that what you think is correct?

Answer (score 1):

As the definition from the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/carry+the+torch) says:

> - To fight for someone or something and encourage or lead others to do the same.
> - To lead or participate in a (figurative) crusade.

So

> The women who inspire us to carry the torch and continue the work.

means those women who, the speaker says, continue to inspire the group to advocate and work for the cause, the MeTo movement.

"Carry the torch" is an idiom.

---

Bu contrast, to "carry **a** torch for soemone" means  to have a continuing romatic desire for someone, usually a desire not returned by its object. A [the free dictionary says](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/torch):

> To be in love with someone, especially secretly and/or unrequitedly.

This is a quite different idiom, but it is easily confused with the above.